# Issue in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwitE.png) At marked position cursor is not visibled while navigating with right arrow key.

Note: while clicking on that position cursor is visible and while navigating with left arrow cursor is visible. This issue occurring at end to the row of contenteditable div

cursor position should be visible in that location while navigating with right arrow key

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.